# 2 question about dirichlet series generating functions

Tags: dirichlet-series

my question is , is there a sequence so we have the Dirichlet series

$$ \frac{\zeta(s+1/2)}{\zeta(s)}= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{a(n)}{n^s} $$

and the second is, given the dirichlet series for the division function

$$ \zeta (s) \zeta(s-a) =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{\sigma _{a}(n)}{n^s} $$

for some $ a > 0 $ , is there a closed formula for

$$ \sum_{x \ge n}\sigma _{a} (n) =A(x) $$

Comment: Try applying Perron's formula to the known Dirichlet generating function. Asymptotics of the average order sums are known and given [here](https://dlmf.nist.gov/27.11).

Answer (score 3):

There is no closed formula for
$$\sum_{n\leq x}\sigma_a(n) $$
but plenty of good approximations are known, from summation by parts and [Dirichlet's hyperbola method](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/tag/dirichlet-hyperbola-method/). About your first question, since:
$$ \frac{1}{\zeta(s)} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{\mu(n)}{n^s},\qquad \zeta\left(s+\tfrac{1}{2}\right) = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1/\sqrt{n}}{n^s} $$
by taking
$$ a(n)=\sum_{d\mid n}\frac{\mu\left(\tfrac{n}{d}\right)}{\sqrt{d}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\sum_{d\mid n}\mu(d)\sqrt{d}$$
we get
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{a(n)}{n^s} = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{s+1/2}}\prod_{p\mid n}\left(1-\sqrt{p}\right)=\frac{\zeta\left(s+\tfrac{1}{2}\right)}{\zeta(s)} $$
as wanted, by [Dirichlet's convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet_convolution).